# How to add a custom validation to Magento prototype

Tags: magento, prototypejs

I want to make a simple url validator for some custom fields. I tried the default ones (adding the class `validate-url` or  `validate-clean-url` to the input) - but these don't work quite as I would like them to, so I want to write some of my own javascript, but integrated with the prototype validation.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can do this?

I didn't find anything helpful in my searches, and I am not very Prototype-savy (worked mostly with jQuery).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can create your own custom validation function using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var theForm = new VarienForm('theForm', true);
    Validation.add('validate-must-be-baz','You failed to enter baz!',function(the_field_value){
        if(the_field_value == 'baz')
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

</script>
```

See  http://magento-quickies.tumblr.com/post/6579512188/magento-custom-form-validation

or

```
if(Validation) {       
   Validation.addAllThese([     
    [
        'validation-myown',      
        'Please insert proper word',   
        function(v,r){ return v.indexOf('valid')==-1?false:true } 
    ],
   [ ]   
])
}
```

see http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/custom-javascript-form-validators

Comment: New resource with same person in mind and solution to this question: https://alanstorm.com/magento-custom-form-validation/

Answer (score 4):

In /js/prototype/validation.js (or the files for this kind of thing you have). You have a section with an array of :

classname :message on fail : function(v){your check return true/false;} to check if v is valid or not

This section is around line 420.

You can add your validation to this array or modify validate-url here is what it looks like :

```
 ['validate-url', 'Please enter a valid URL. Protocol is required (http://, https:// or ftp://)', function (v) {
            v = (v || '').replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '');
            return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^(http|https|ftp):\/\/(([A-Z0-9]([A-Z0-9_-]*[A-Z0-9]|))(\.[A-Z0-9]([A-Z0-9_-]*[A-Z0-9]|))*)(:(\d+))?(\/[A-Z0-9~](([A-Z0-9_~-]|\.)*[A-Z0-9~]|))*\/?(.*)?$/i.test(v)
        }],
```

Edit : R.S answered maybe better by showing how to do without changing the js file. More convenient ;)