# How to set maximum value of date attribute in Magento?

Tags: magento, attributes, adminhtml

I want to set maximum value of "Date of Birth" (dob) attribute of the customer.

I want to set this date only earlier than today (not for future). After change I want to have JS validation on adminhtml backend in customer edit screen.

I want to update this attribute in setup scripts within my module. How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to code it. Admin panel uses **Prototype Validation**: you can extend by creating a custom JS file with your validation rules, in the form:

```
 if(Validation) {
   Validation.add AllThese ([
    ['validate-dob',    // class/rule name
     'DOB cannot be in the future',  // Error message
      function (v) {
         //  TODO: validation of input, 'v' being the input.
         // return true (input is ok) or false
     }]
      // more rules here, if needed..
  ])};
```

Then dynamically add 'validate-dob' class to customer dob input field. You can do it in this file too.
Add your custom file to be loaded in the admin theme in **adminhtml default layout** main.xml.

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own custom validation,

```
var theForm = new VarienForm('theForm', true);
Validation.add('validate-dob','You failed to enter baz!',function(the_field_value){
    if(check date)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

see [How to add a custom validation to Magento prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027613/magento-prototype-custom-validation)

Then including the js file using local.xml

```
 <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>path/to/validation_dob.js</name></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```